# Can a team lead force an employee to change careers?

Tags: career-development, job-change, conflict

A colleague of mine held a position which was in her career path. But the higher-ups deemed that the position had "no visibility" (i.e. no visible positive effect) to the team. So they slowly transitioned her to an entry level position she once held. She feels that she was treated unfairly since she was technically demoted even though she performed well in that job. What's worse, the current job she holds is nowhere in her intended career path and her previous position still exists but is now shared amongst our team leads. So I'd like to ask if my colleague has any real grievance and if so, what can she do? This change in careers is making her miserable

Clarifications:
Her performance was based on the positive effect on the team, but the "visibility" mentioned is for the overall contribution to the department the team belonged to.
The company is in the Philippines

Comment: Your description seems contradictory, please clarify this: if higher-ups think that she performed well in her job, why did they also claim that it had no positive effect?

Comment: "So I'd like to ask if my colleague has any real grievance and if so, what can she do?"  -  VTC - asking for legal advice and too broad.  We would need to at least know where this is (country), but we would refer your friend to an employment attorney.

Comment: Surely "previous position still exists but is now shared amongst our team leads" = "previous position does **not** still exist"? The work still needs to be done, but there is not deemed to be a need for a person to be dedicated to doing that work.

Comment: Often when they decide they don't need your position, they get rid of you, trransitioning to another role was actually the kindest thing they could have done and indicates they value her.

Comment: Instead of "grievance" or even "changing employers" what about trying normal discussion first? For example, if she is valued in the company, but she doesn't feel like her current role is putting her on the right career path, AND her performance has been good, would it be so bad to talk to your bosses and say something like "I like it here, but I feel like my current role is not growing my career in the right direction."

Answer (score 3):

If she does not like the way her job description has been nuked and her job restructured, she has the option to change employer.  If her team leads have no issue with her performance, then they should have no problem acting as her reference. She needs to make sure that their complaint is about her "visibility" not her performance, however.

The rule of thumb is, of course, "better to be happy elsewhere than to be unhappy here". Especially if she has nothing here to look forward to but career stagnation and increasingly negative performance reviews due to career stagnation. If she is unhappy with what she is doing, the chances are pretty good that they will eventually be unhappy with her, too- It's wonderful how what goes around comes around in this world, isn't it? :) In terms of timing, it's best to break out of that vicious circle before it becomes a circle.